# My apps are using 3.7GB of storage on my iPad, how can I check which app is using what amount?

Tags: ipad, storage

Is there a breakdown that can be viewed somewhere?

Comment: On a Mac, ~/Music/iTunes/Mobile Applications/ has all your apps.  I think it includes apps you've uninstalled, and doesn't include data, but it's a good first approximation.

Answer (score 4):

On iTunes itself, on the App section of your Library (top section in the left side navigation bar) you can see how big Apps are by switching to List view (iTunes menu bar -> View -> As List).

Comment: Thanks that helps but I also wanted to find out what data was actually stored with the app on the ipad. I found it in the obvious place, under Apps in the Ipad window in itunes where you can organize your apps. It lets you sort by size as well.

Answer (score 4):

On the iPad If you go to Settings -> General -> Usage and a list of your apps will pop up right there, along with the amount of storage that they're taking up.